# Is javafx Scene Builder 8.5.0 support for java jdk 17?

Tags: java, javafx, installation, scenebuilder

I just want to know, is Scene Builder 8.5.0 support for both java jdk 17 and java jdk 8.

Answer (score 1):

The [*Scene Builder* product page](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) seems pretty clear:

> Scene Builder 17.0.0 was released on Sep 29, 2021.
>
> You can use this Scene Builder version together with Java 11 and higher.

… and:

> Scene Builder 8.5.0 is for users who are still on Java 8. It was released on Jun 5, 2018.

Java 8, 11, and 17 are the [LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) versions of Java.

|  | Java 8 | Java 11+ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Scene Builder version: | 8.5.0 | 17.0.0 |